# Embed fonts in Actionscript 3 project

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, fonts, flash-builder, embed

I'm trying to embed a font to my Actionscript 3 project in Flash Builder 4.5. I've found several examples and fixes, but none of them has my problem. My embedded font shows up in the enumeratedFonts list and I get no errors, but it just falls back to the system default font when I use it in my TextFormat. I've tried using several Embed()-attributes and compiler-arguments from this post: http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.*;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.*;

public class FontTest extends Sprite {
    [Embed(source="assets/Nanami.otf", fontName="NanamiRegular", embedAsCFF= "false")]
    private var myEmbeddedFont:Class;

    public function FontTest() {
        var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(false);

        for(var i:int = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
            trace(fonts[i].fontName);
        }

        var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        fmt.color = 0xFF0000;
        fmt.font = "NanamiRegular";
        fmt.size = 32;

        var tlfTxt:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
        tlfTxt.defaultTextFormat = fmt;
        tlfTxt.embedFonts = true;
        tlfTxt.border = true;
        tlfTxt.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
        tlfTxt.wordWrap = true;
        tlfTxt.width = 300;
        tlfTxt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        tlfTxt.x = tlfTxt.y = 40;
        tlfTxt.rotation = 20;
        addChild(tlfTxt);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to change the `fontName` to something else, like "testfontname" and provide a font-family, like "testfontfamily"

```
[Embed(source="assets/Nanami.otf", fontName="testfontname", fontFamily="testfontfamily" embedAsCFF= "false")]
```

then embed it with that name:

```
fmt.font = "testfontname";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've changed fontName to "testfontname" and added fontFamily without any luck. I've also downloaded another font (ttf), but that din't work either.

Comment: Strange. I assume you also update the font-name on the TextFormat? 
I havent used font-embedding with tlf-text, but with normal textfields it works fine here:
    [Embed(source="fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", fontName="DefaultFont", fontFamily="spittfonts", mimeType="application/x-font-truetype", embedAsCFF="false")] 
    public static var defaultFont:Class;

    new TextFormat("DefaultFont", 12, 0x000000);

Comment: Damn, you got it! Changed TLFTextField to TextField and now it works! Strange that TLFTextField doesn't work. I've been trying to solve this for hours and I thought that the problem was embedding the font. Thanks Marijn!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TLFTextField, you must change "embedAsCFF" value to true, because TLFText using new Flash Text Engine.